# Pushing messages from cakephp to client

Tags: android, cakephp, push-notification

I have built an examination system on cakephp. Now I want to add one more module in which students can subscribe to discussions related a particular question paper.

In future, I have plan to make an android app using same backend code.

My query is -
"How can I implement PUSH message feature in Cake?"

Requirement is to push a message to all subscribers:
(1). If they are on that page, their page gets refreshed with new message
(2). If they have android application installed, they get a notification of new message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bandroid%5d%5bphp%5d%20push

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an external library/code as default CakePHP does not include any functionality to handle Push notifications.

--- Solution 1 ---

External library for send Android push notifications:

[AndroidPusher](https://github.com/gonzalo123/androidpusher)

[Documentation about how to load external libraries in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)

--- Solution 2 ---

CakePHP 2.x tools for sending push notifications to iPhone, Android and BlackBerry:

[cakephp-push-notification](https://github.com/alexmcroberts/cakephp-push-notification)